# jquery check if dynamic created element with ID exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, popup

jquery-1.10.2.js & jquery-ui-1.10.4.js

code snippet to create a dynamic dialog with dynamic ID:

```
var dynamicId = "dynamic-popup-1";
var popup1Selector = "#" + dynamicId;
var popup1 = $("#popupTemplate").clone().attr({"id": dynamicId});
$("body").append(popup1);
$(function() {
    popup1.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
    });
});
popup1.dialog("open");
```

The popup is displayed after the above code snippet is executed. From firebug, I can see an element  is created and added to the DOM tree.

But I cannot use the following to check if the popup has already been created:
    if ($(popup1Selector).length) {}

$(popup1Selector) won't find anything even though the popup is right there on top of the page; and the  element shows up in firebug as well.

Comment: Adding a common class to dynamic elememts would be a simple solution.